# 2 external displays via HP Thunderbolt G2

Tags: thunderbolt

I`m completely new to Linux. I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
I work in dual boot with Win 11 Pro.
I want to use my 2 external displays via HP Thunderbolt G2 docking station (my laptop is HP Power G7).
I already enabled thunderbolt in laptop BIOS so it works fine in Windows but when plugged it to newly installed Ubuntu, both ext displays are black as is laptop display.
Am I missing some package for thunderbolt dock in linux?

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Michal